# Translation of "rocky road" in "it will be more of a rocky road than before"

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

I would like to know if "pedregoso" is appropriate for "rocky road" in below text, please help me to check it, thanks.

> This leg of the path will be when people’s genuine stature is revealed as well as whether or not they have true faith. Since this leg of the path will be more arduous than any that has been led in the past, and it will be more of a **rocky road** than before, it is called “the last leg of the path.”

Translation for the last sentence:

> Como esta etapa de la senda será más ardua que cualquier otra que se haya guiado en el pasado, y como será un camino más **pedregoso** que antes, se denomina “la última etapa de la senda”.

Comment: Welcome to [Spanish.SE]! Could you explain the meaning of "rocky road" in the context of the text? What do you understand by "rocky road"? I just want to be sure as most of us are not native English speakers.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea with this situation. It means "full of frustrations"

Comment: It seems then that "rocky road" carries a second meaning ("full of distractions") that "camino pedregoso" does not have in Spanish. So I recommend to just translate "rocky road" as "camino lleno de distracciones" or search for a similar modism in Spanish (maybe "camino tortuoso").

Comment: @Charlie I think it just means a difficult path (in this case figuratively) so i suspect _camino tortuoso_ would do the trick.

Comment: "camino pedregoso" does not exist in Spanish?

Comment: @Charlie, the meaning of rocky road as "full of frustrations" it's a connotative meaning that things will get hard.  so "camino pedregoso" , "camino arduo", have the same connotation of hardship.

Comment: @CeliaTalyn yes, indeed, but to me the figurative sense of "camino pedregoso" is weaker than the one in other expressions such as "camino tortuoso" or "camino lleno de obstáculos". But I suppose that may depend on the reader.

Comment: I don't like "que se haya guiado". "que se haya tomado/seguido" would be a better choice.

Comment: I agree with @Gustavson - and would go a bit farther -- this is a mistake in the translation.  "Guiar" just doesn't work here at all. // For *rocky road* I'd prefer *el camino estará más accidentado que antes* (got the idea from linguee.com).

Answer (score 3):

This translation can be considered correct:

> Como esta etapa de la senda será más ardua que cualquier otra que se haya guiado en el pasado, y como será un camino más **pedregoso** que antes, se denomina “la última etapa de la senda”.

We get that **rocky road** is being used to describe the meaning that something is going to be hard as a rocky road, but not a rocky road itself.

This is connotative language, and it's transmitting an idea or feeling rather than a fact or a denotation.

in this context, **camino pedregoso** has the same meaning, yet, is very commonly used.

So an easy to understand and actually used form is **camino arduo**. And as the whole paragraph is talking about paths (**caminos**), then to keep the semantic of the phrase, then we will keep using forms that are related to paths.

So, while the translation is correct, it is better understood if we use more common, connotative words and phrases in Spanish like **arduo/difícil/complicado/severo/**, as these words are talking about feelings more like things (not explicit rocks as the use of explicit elements is less connotative in Spanish).

This translation can be considered accurate:

> Como esta etapa de la senda será más ardua que cualquier otra que se haya guiado en el pasado, y como será un camino más **arduo** que antes, se denomina “la última etapa de la senda”.

Remember, there's no unique translation for connotative language.

Comment: "camino severo" is not a normal collocation.